# Get-Process -computername pipeline input works only with the first name

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Get-Process accepts -computername parameter by pipeline (ByPropertyName).
The file I import looks like:

```
computername
sql01
sql02
sql03
```

When I pipe it, I'll get the processes only from the first computer in the list (sql01)?

```
$a = Import-Csv C:\temp\computers.txt
$a | get-process -name dwm # output only from the first computer in the list
get-process dwm -ComputerName $a.computername # here correct output from 3 computers
```

Comment: What you're doing seems correct and should work, the cmdlet takes input by property name in PS 5.1. This seems like a bug?

Comment: or a feature? ;-)

Comment: Can you confirm that `($a | get-process -name dwm).Count` and `(get-process dwm -ComputerName $a.computername).Count` are different ?

Comment: definitely, I got 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It looks like you've hit a bug in *Windows PowerShell*** - see bottom section for details.

- The **bug is unlikely to get fixed,** given that Windows PowerShell will only see critical fixes going forward.
- You are already aware of the **workaround**: pass the array of computer names *as an argument* to `-ComputerName` instead of via the pipeline.

  ```sh
  # Windows PowerShell only.
  Get-Process dwm -ComputerName $a.computername
  ```
- From a broader perspective, **consider switching to using *PowerShell*'s [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote)**, where only the *general-purpose* **[`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)** cmdlet facilitates execution of *arbitrary commands* remotely, using a modern, firewall-friendly transport. Similarly, the **[CIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/) cmdlets** (e.g. [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)), which use the same transport, should be preferred over the obsolete WMI cmdlets they supersede (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`).

  ```sh
  # Works in both PowerShell editions, assuming the target computers
  # are set up for PowerShell remoting.
  # Note: Invoke-Command does NOT support passing computer names via the pipeline.
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $a.computername { Get-Process dwm -ComputerName }
  ```

  - Note that the **`-ComputerName` parameters on *purpose-specific* cmdlets** such as `Get-Process` and `Restart-Computer` ***aren't available in PowerShell (Core) 7+ anymore***, and **neither are the WMI cmdlets**, because they are based on [.NET Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.71)), a form of remoting unrelated to PowerShell that has  been declared [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/remoting-apis-obsolete) and is therefore not part of .NET Core / .NET 5+. By definition, the bug at hand therefore doesn't affect PowerShell (Core).

---

**Bug details:**

The bug is specific to the combination of:

- providing objects that have a `.ComputerName` property via the pipeline in order to bind the property values to the `-ComputerName` parameter
- targeting processes by *name(s)*, via the (possibly positionally implied) `-Name` parameter, or targeting *all* processes (by neither passing a `-Name` nor an `-Id` argument)

In other words: targeting processes *by PID* (process ID), via the `-Id` parameter is *not* affected - but using `-Id` *remotely* is only useful if you've previously obtained a PID from a given computer and if you're targeting only *one* computer.

In Windows PowerShell, [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp)'s `-ComputerName` parameter is designed to bind objects supplied via the pipeline that have a `.ComputerName` property to the `-ComputerName` parameter:

```sh
WinPS> Get-Help Get-Process -Parameter ComputerName

-ComputerName <System.String[]>
    # ...
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    # ...
```

However, as you've observed, only the *first* computer name bound this way is honored by `Get-Process` in combination with `-Name` - any remaining ones are quietly ignored:

```sh
# Target the local machine (.) and a NON-EXISTENT machine ('NOSUCH')
WinPS> [pscustomobject] @{ ComputerName='.' }, 
       [pscustomobject] @{ ComputerName='NOSUCH' } | 
         Get-Process -Name powershell

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    970      48   170860      29120      56.41   4656   1 powershell
```

That is, the local machine's PowerShell process(es) are reported, and the non-existent computer name was quietly ignored.
Note: *Any* subsequent computer names are ignored, whether they refer to existing computers or not. Using a non-existent one should conspicuously surface as an error.
If you replace `-Name powershell` with `-Id $PID`, you will indeed see the error.

The problem is *not* one of parameter binding, as output from a [`Trace-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command) call shows:

```sh
WinPS> Trace-Command -pshost -name ParameterBinding { 
         [pscustomobject] @{ ComputerName='.' }, 
         [pscustomobject] @{ ComputerName='NOSUCH' } | Get-Process -Name powershell 
       }

DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Get-Process]
# ...
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Get-Process]
# ...
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Get-Process]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
# ...
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [ComputerName] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [.] to parameter [ComputerName]
# ...
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [ComputerName] SUCCESSFUL
# ...
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Get-Process]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [NOSUCH] to parameter [ComputerName]
# ...
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [ComputerName] SUCCESSFUL
# ...
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

`BIND arg [.]` and `BIND arg [NOSUCH]`, followed by a `SUCCESSFUL` status, indicate that both computer names were properly bound.

In other words: the bug must be in the code that subsequently *uses* the correctly bound parameters.

Comment: I don't think this is the first cmdlet that I see failing when bound by property name in Windows PS. Also, not WinPS but AD Module (`New-ADUser` has a similar issue). Thanks for answering

Comment: @mklement0: you're my absolute hero! Thanks a lot! I'm kind of proud of myself either: discovered 2 bugs (you remember the one with $error[]?), you solved two of them, nice job! ;-) P.S. I'm looking for a working example of a test unit for PowerShell (I need it for an unattended SQL-Server Installation, checking for many parameters, the must be true), can you advice where to look for it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @Purclot; my pleasure; indeed, nice job on discovering two obscure bugs. I'm not sure I understand your question, but in case you're looking for a test framework for PowerShell, use [Pester](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pester/).

Comment: the pleasure is mine! Yes, I need a test framework for PS and I'll give a try with Pester.