# Piping parameters into cmdlet

Tags: powershell

This was done for testing and we have the solution but I would like to dig deeper.
I have a file list.txt that contains names of computers:

```
name
computer1
computer2
computer3
...
```

when I try

```
Import-Csv .\list.txt | Select-Object -property @{n="computername";e={$_.name}} | Get-Service
```

we get an error "Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name '@{computername=computer1}'." Which I understand as Get-Service trying to map computername=computer1 to the parameter "name" (name="computername=computer1") even though the parameter "computername" is specified.

My solution was to add the "name" parameter and it works as expected

```
Import-Csv .\list.txt | Select-Object -property @{n="computername";e={$_.name}} | Get-Service -name *
```

My question is, **why**? Get-Service should accept pipeline input byPropertyName and it recognizes computername. Why doesn't it bind it unless I specify another parameter? Neither "name", nor "computername" is required. Also

```
Get-Service
```

and

```
Get-Service -computername "computer1"
```

both work without specifying "name".

Comment: Possible another bug :) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72292236/15339544